# cycle.js - Embed component in jsx of other component

Tags: javascript, rxjs, jsx, rxjs5

I want to embed a cycle.js component inside jsx.

I have seen examples in the [documentation](https://cycle.js.org/components.html) of embedding components inside other components but not when using JSX and I can't find any examples online. I am quite new to the whole reactive thing such as RxJs.

In the example in the [documentation](https://cycle.js.org/components.html) they just seem to plonk the child component into the parent component (now I can see they pass it in to the xs.combine() function):

```
  const childVDom$ = labeledSlider.DOM;
  const childValue$ = labeledSlider.value;

  const vdom$ = xs.combine(childValue$, childVDom$)
    .map(([value, childVDom]) =>
      div([
        childVDom,
        div({style: {
```

But when I do it in JSX it causes it to just return undefined to the DOM where the component goes (see near the bottom of this code):

```
import { html } from 'snabbdom-jsx'
import * as dom from '@cycle/dom'
import Button from 'components/button'
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
import styles from './index.styl'

export default function Title(sources) {
  const sinks = {
    DOM: view(sources)
  }
  return sinks
}

function view(sources) {

  const props$ = Rx.Observable.of({
    label: 'Try Now'
  })

  const childSources = {
    DOM: sources.DOM,
    props: props$
  }

const button = Button(childSources)
  const vdom$ = props$
    .map(() =>
      <div className="container has-text-centered">
        <p className="logo">
          <img className={`${styles.img}`}
            src="src/img/logo_transparent_background.png"
          />
        </p>
        <h4 className="subtitle is-4">
          xxx
      </h4>
        {button.DOM}<------- component
      </div>)

  return vdom$
}
```

Now button.DOM is an observable:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
import { html } from 'snabbdom-jsx'

export default function Button(sources) {
  const sinks = {
    DOM: view(sources)
  }
  return sinks
}

function view(sources) {
  const props$ = sources.props
  const vdom$ = props$
    .map(props =>
      <a className="button is-primary is-large is-outlined">
        {props.label}
      </a>
    )
  return vdom$
}
```

How do I add it to the jsx without it being undefined? I'm using RxJs.

**EDIT: I have now come up with this which still has the same undefined outcome but seems like it is on the right track:**

```
function view(sources) {

  const props$ = Rx.Observable.of({
    label: 'Try Now'
  })

  const childSources = {
    DOM: sources.DOM,
    props: props$
  }

const button = Button(childSources)
const childVDom$ = button.DOM
  const vdom$ = Rx.Observable.of(childVDom$)
    .map((childVDom) =>
      <div className="container has-text-centered">
        <p className="logo">
          <img className={`${styles.img}`}
            src="src/img/logo_transparent_background.png"
          />
        </p>
        <h4 className="subtitle is-4">
          xxx
      </h4>
        {childVDom}
      </div>)

  return vdom$
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `button.DOM` was already a stream so it could be mapped directly. I was mapping the wrong thing. This is the solution:

```
function view(sources) {

  const props$ = Rx.Observable.of({
    label: 'Try Now'
  })

  const childSources = {
    DOM: sources.DOM,
    props: props$
  }

const button = Button(childSources)
const childVDom$ = button.DOM
  const vdom$ = childVDom$
    .map((childVDom) =>
      <div className="container has-text-centered">
        <p className="logo">
          <img className={`${styles.img}`}
            src="src/img/logo_transparent_background.png"
          />
        </p>
        <h4 className="subtitle is-4">
          xxx
      </h4>
        {childVDom}
      </div>)

  return vdom$
}
```